# How to trigger click event in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to trigger click event in textarea?

I tried:

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#txtid').val('something');
$('#txtid').trigger('click');
});
```

**html**

```
<textarea id='txtid' rows='5' cols='20'></teaxtarea>
```

But the click is not happened. What is wrong in the code.

I tried the focus event like this

```
   $('#txtid').focus(); //this worked
```

But i need to trigger a click event after getting the value to textarea.

Please help..

Comment: Triggering an event will run the defined function - not the native function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set a click event handler first.

Edit 1: Since you try to trigger the click event within document ready, you have to declare the click event handler within the document ready event handler, even before you trigger it.

Html:

```
<textarea id='txtid' rows='5' cols='20'></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#txtid').click(function() { alert('clicked'); }); 
  $('#txtid').val('something');
  $('#txtid').trigger('click');
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/j03n46bf/

Edit 2:

Since you want the event to be triggered after you get a value to your textarea, **Milind Anantwar** is right, you have to use the onchange event:

Same Html, different jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#txtid').change(function() { alert('Value changed'); }); 
  $('#txtid').val('something');
  $('#txtid').trigger('change');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sb2pohan/

Edit 3:

After some comments:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#txtid').click(function() { changeDiv(); }); 
  $('#txtid').focus(); // Set Focus on Textarea (now caret appears)
  $('#txtid').val('something'); // Fill content (caret will be moved to the end of value)
  $('#txtid').trigger('click'); // Click Handler will be executed
});

function changeDiv() {
// do some stuff;
}
```

Edit 4:
Working test.html (Tested in IE, FF, Chrome):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#txtid").click(function() { changeDiv(); });
                $("#txtid").focus();
                $("#txtid").val("value");
                $("#txtid").trigger("click");
            });
            function changeDiv() {
                $('#changeDiv').css("background-color","red");
                $('#changeDiv').html("changed content");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="txtid"></textarea>
        <div id="changeDiv" style="background-color: green; width: 100px; height: 100px;">start content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need the onclick should be triggered on page onload and the curser should blink on textarea. Hope you got it!!

Comment: Okay, click tirggerd on page load is solved within my first Javascript Snippet


What do you mean with "the cursor should blink on textarea" ?

Comment: I mean when we type something that the pointer I mean it curser, I tried your code but curser not coming!! My requirement is that in page load I am populating some content into text area, and after that it should fire a click or onchange event without user interaction!!

Comment: Aaaah now I get it.

You want the caret to appear, after you pull some value in your textarea ...


Ja this would only be possible with .focus(); unfortunatelly focus() does not work in my jsfiddle :-/


So I tried it with a html file


Just take my first Javascript, define your click handler as you like (what ever it should do) and after the `$('#textid').trigger('click');` 
you do a 
`$('#textid').focus();`

What do you want your click handler to do?
Or do you only want to let the caret appear?
If so, you would not need any click stuff just put the focus after you filled the value

Comment: If you want the caret to appear behind the value you are setting you have to set the focus before to set the value `$('#txtid').focus(); $('#txtid').val('something');$('#txtid').trigger('click');`

Comment: my requirement is a way that in onload I need to fire onclick on textarea and in onclick I am changing th content of other div. Now hope you understand. I tried to fire the same code but the div content still not changing, but if I manually click on the textarea it does. What to do buddy!!

Comment: You put the code that changes the content of a nother div in a function (e.g. "**changeDiv();**") then you call this function in the click handler `$('#txtid').click(function() { changeDiv(); });` instead of `$('#txtid').click(function() { alert('clicked'); });`
That should do the trick

Comment: I did the same but it is not auto triggering. It works only if I clicked manually on textarea!!

Comment: Strange, works fine for me - I'll post my working test.html in my answer

Comment: Posted it as Edit #4 in my Answer, to big for comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

You probable need to trigger change event:

```
 $('#txtid').trigger('change');
```

Comment: I need the onclick should be triggered on page onload and the curser should blink on textarea. Hope you got it!!

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) says, the event click/Change needs exits to that works so your Javascrtipt should be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#txtid').val('something');
  $('#txtid').on('change', function(){
    alert('hi!!!!!');
  })
$('#txtid').trigger('change');  
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pbc9j49w/)

Comment: You have to declare the click event handler before you trigger the event. Your solution only works, if you click the textarea. But triggering the click event on document ready won't call your handler, because it is not declared at that moment

Comment: mmmm here that works http://jsfiddle.net/wabttk8y/ but whether go to the logic, that you says it's true, we are attaching a click event that does not exist.

Comment: True, I think the solution would be to use the change event, because it should be triggerd, AFTER putting a value in the textarea

Comment: @WilfredoP I need the onclick should be triggered on page onload and the curser should blink on textarea. Hope you got it!

Answer (score 0):

To see it works first define click listener, then trigger the click event.

http://jsfiddle.net/gfkjs5ps/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#txtid').val('something');
  $('#txtid').click(function(){alert("clicked");}); //define click listener
  $('#txtid').click();    //click text area
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For native Javascript is working for me:

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').select();
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply `$('#txtid').click();` will trigger the click event.